# Angular2 build failing in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: angular, azure-devops

I am trying to build a solution (VS 2017 RC) which uses TypeScript 2.1. When it builds in Visual Studio Team Services it fails with the following error message (amongst many others)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe --project "C:\a\1\s\Angular\tsconfig.json"
[error]Angular\node_modules\rxjs\Observable.d.ts(29,33): Error TS1138: Build: Parameter declaration expected.
```

From a bit of googling it appears that this error occurs because of an outdated version of the transcompiler. How do I get VSTS to use version 2.1? is this even possible?

Here is my package.json file to clarify what I am doing:

```
{
  "name": "ng2-startvs",
  "version": "1.0.0", 
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\"",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.34",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "typings": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig is now this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

Here is my build definition:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <ProjectGuid>{B2A7EAE0-F8C3-4B1E-A3BB-F1F4ECB4A30D}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <OutputPath>bin</OutputPath>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.1</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{4A0DDDB5-7A95-4FBF-97CC-616D07737A77}" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="app\app.component.css" />
    <Content Include="app\app.component.html" />
    <Content Include="index.html" />
    <Content Include="systemjs.config.js" />
    <Content Include="web.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="package.json" />
    <Content Include="tsconfig.json" />
    <Content Include="typings.json" />
    <None Include="web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>web.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>web.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="app\app.component.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="app\app.module.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="app\main.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="app\shared\models\counter.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="app\counters\counter-insert.component.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="app\counters\counter-edit.component.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>AngularCounter</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets')" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>23097</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:23098/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>true</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Might want to check if tsc 2.1 is installed on your build server first. After that, double check your build process to see how tsc is being invoked. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highest version of TypeScript on [Hosted Agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool#software-on-the-hosted-build-server) is 2.0.6.

Refer to these steps to deal that issue if you are using Visual Studio Build to build project:

1. Add/Install [Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/) to your project
2. Edit your project file (.csproj)

   a.) Configure MSBuild to use the NuGet package's props file.

   ```
   <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props')" />
   <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />-->
   ```

   b.) Configure MSBuild to use the NuGet package's targets file.

   ```
   <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets')" />
   <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />-->
   ```

   If it is .Net Core project, add this code to  section of .xproj file

   ```
   <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.1.4</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
   <TscToolPath>C:\Users\[user account]\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild\2.1.4\tools\tsc</TscToolPath>
   ```

If you are using tsc command directly, for example, [quickstart demo](https://github.com/angular/quickstart): npm run tsc, the TypeScript dependency is defined in package.json and corresponding TypeScript will be installed during npm install build step, then it uses corresponding version of tsc tool to compile when invoke npm run tsc command through npm build step/task.

On the other hand, there is [TypeScript compiler package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler/), so you could include this package in your project, then compile typescript files through tsc.exe tool within that package.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have included the package.json command above to show what I am doing more clearly. I think this means I am using the tsc command directly? I tyried changing the version of TypeScript to 2.0.6 as suggested but the build still fails with the same error message. I wasn't clear which subset of the above suggestions applied to my situation. Thanks

Comment: @johnstaveley First, why do you need to compile typescript file in node_modules? Just exclude that folder in tsconfig.json if you don't need to compile. Secondly, try to add "tscv": "tsc --version" to Script section of package.json, then invoke npm run tscv through npm build step/task. Thirdly, provide the detail steps of your build definition.

Comment: According to this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html the node_modules directory should be excluded by default

Comment: @johnstaveley What's the detail code of your tsconfig.json, the node_module directory is excluded by default if you don't specify exclude files or folders (no exclude section in tsconfig.json). On the other hand, could you share a simple project on the OneDrive.

Comment: I added it anyway. I then added the tscv commands, this fails in build with the message ##[error]Only one command should be used for npm. Use 'Arguments' input for additional arguments.

Comment: @johnstaveley Refer to the steps that I provided to modify project file. (Install Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package, edit project file ...)

Comment: Hi, why do I need to do this just to get it to build remotely? It builds fine and works locally without adding anything. Ps. Yes I will try!

Comment: I am now getting: packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\tools\microsoft.TypeScript.targets(231,7): Error MSB4064: The "OutputLogFile" parameter is not supported by the "VsTsc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.

Comment: and packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.1.4\tools\microsoft.TypeScript.targets(222,5): Error MSB4063: The "VsTsc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

Comment: @johnstaveley There isn't the Typescript 2.1.4 installed in Hosted agent, however it is existing on your machine, so you can build it in local. Provide the detail build steps here. On the other hand, can you share a simple project on the OneDrive?

Comment: I got rid of the error above by using Install-Package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild -version 1.8.11. Now I am back to the original error of building typescript in node_modules. Here is my sample project https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0c0zpmuf82nh78/Angular%20Test%20Project.zip?dl=0

Comment: @johnstaveley Install 2.1.4 version (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/) instead.

Comment: ok, bizarre, now I don't get the OutputLogFile error I got above when I had the 2.1.4 version installed!

Comment: @johnstaveley What's the result when you build project through TFS build now?

Comment: Now building! Thanks for all your help